# How to update my index when I first render my page using React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I update my index the first time I render the page, everything is working as I want but the first time it renders it returns the `undefined` so I can't get the info at the first time rendering.

First-time refresh/ render the page:

[image: First render]

After swipe or click next and then return to the previous item, it'll update correctly.

[image: Render again]

Here's my code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import './home.css'
import { supabase } from '../../supabaseClient'
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'
import SwiperCore, { Pagination,Navigation } from 'swiper';
import 'swiper/css'

SwiperCore.use([Pagination,Navigation]);
function Home(){
    
    const [animeDetail, setAnimeDetail] = useState([])
    const [swiperIndex, setSwiperIndex] = useState()

    useEffect(async ()=>{
        fetchAnime()
    }, [])

    async function fetchAnime() {
        const { data } = await supabase
            .from ('anime')
            .select ()
            setAnimeDetail(data)
    }

    return (
        <>
        <div className="spacer">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div className="home-section">

            <h2>Home Page</h2>

            <Swiper
            runCallbacksOnInit = {true}
            centeredSlides={true}
            slidesPerView = {7}
            spaceBetween={10}
            loop={false}
            pagination={false} 
         // I set my index to the state here
            onActiveIndexChange={(swiperCore) => {setSwiperIndex(swiperCore.realIndex)}}
            navigation={true} className="mySwiper">
                {animeDetail.map((element, i)=> 
                    (
                    <SwiperSlide key = {i}>
                        <img src={element.anime_image}/>
                    </SwiperSlide>
                    )
                    )}
            </Swiper>

        {/* Current index of active slide */}
        {console.log(swiperIndex)}
        {/* The specific info contains on active slide */}
        {console.log(animeDetail[swiperIndex])}
        {/* An array list contains each anime */}
        {console.log(animeDetail)}
        </div>
        </>
    )

}
export default Home
```

Edit: After I tried @Dae Hyeon Mun's solution, the problem is still there.

[image: The code]

I still get the `undefined` when the first time renders/refresh the page.

[image: undefined value]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with `0` as the initial state value for the index:

```js
// const [swiperIndex, setSwiperIndex] = useState() // before
const [swiperIndex, setSwiperIndex] = useState(0) // after
```

On the first render, you will only have the data that you provide as the initial values to your state (empty array and `0`). [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) doesn't run until **after** the first render.

Comment: Thanks, I've used useState(0) before but I really can't figure it out at that moment, because I set a different index of the Slide differently compare to the initial State index, but thanks for pointing this basic back, I just realize that I just need to match the InitialSlide of Swiper with first time render of the initial State.

Answer (score 0):

Try fix code as below

```
 useEffect(async () => {

    const { data } = await supabase
        .from ('anime')
        .select()

    setAnimeDetail(data)
    }, [])

   if (animeDetail.length === 0) {
     return <div>Loading</div>;
   }
   .... rendering //
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but it is still the same.